# Link SKNode to GKAgent2D?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sknode, gameplay-kit

I am new to `GameplayKit` as most are given its lifespan, and have been trying to figure out the following..

I have an `SKNode *enemy` that has already been given quite a bit of work and customization from movement to style, habits, etc. all from `SpriteKit`. My question is such:

- How can I "link" my enemy node to a `GKAgent2D` so that it controls this nodes movements?

I understand that you must create a `GKComponent` and represent this component with a Sprite Node perhaps with a certain texture of choice. But I wanted to know if there was a way to use the built in "control movement" methods that `GameplayKit` offers  on an already existing node. If the answer is "No" please just say so and explain why perhaps? I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is your enemy a GKEntity? If its not I believe you cannot add a GKComponent to it.

If your enemy is a GKEntity than you simply add a GKComponent as an agent. Otherwise you will have to change your enemy class to make it a GKEntity.

The way apple does it in DemoBots is to create a class

```
class AgentComponent: GKAgent2D { }
```

(GKagent is a subclass of GKComponent so its like adding a component)

Than in the entities they need the agents they do this

```
class Enemy: GKEntity ...

let agentComponent = AgentComponent()
    agentComponent.delegate = self
    agentComponent.radius = Float(texture.size().width * 0.3)
    addComponent(agentComponent)
```

and than set the delegates

```
agentDidUpdate

angentWillUpdate
```

These are some good tutorials about this

http://www.raywenderlich.com/119959/gameplaykit-tutorial-entity-component-system-agents-goals-behaviors

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-gameplaykit-part-1--cms-24483